# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSigners')

Tags: testing, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

When I write the code to test my smart contracts I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSigners').

Here is the code:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("KittySwap", function () {
  let KittySwap;
  let Token;
  let owner;
  let addr1;
  let addr2;
  let addrs;
  let provider; // Agrega esta variable

  beforeEach(async function () {
    [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners();
    provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(); // Crea una instancia del proveedor

    KittySwap = await ethers.getContractFactory("KittySwap");
    Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");

    token = await Token.deploy();
    kittySwap = await KittySwap.deploy(token.address);
    await token.transfer(kittySwap.address, 1000000);
  });

  it("Should have correct initial values", async function () {
    expect(await kittySwap.name()).to.equal("Kitty Swap");
    expect(await kittySwap.token()).to.equal(token.address);
    expect(await kittySwap.rate()).to.equal(1000);
  });

  it("Should allow buying tokens", async function () {
    const initialBalance = await token.balanceOf(addr1.address);
    await addr1.sendTransaction({ to: kittySwap.address, value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1") });
    const finalBalance = await token.balanceOf(addr1.address);

    expect(finalBalance.sub(initialBalance)).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("1").mul(1000));
  });

  it("Should allow selling tokens", async function () {
    await token.transfer(addr1.address, 1000);
    await token.connect(addr1).approve(kittySwap.address, 1000);

    const initialBalance = await addr1.getBalance();
    await kittySwap.connect(addr1).sellTokens(1000);
    const finalBalance = await addr1.getBalance();

    expect(finalBalance.sub(initialBalance)).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("1"));
  });
});
```

I've also tried deleting the node_modules folder, installing different versions of @ethers, etc.